# Detect if the selected text spans on the entire line or more lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, textarea

I'm trying to auto-detect if the selection of a textarea contains new lines, or if the full line has been selected.

For example

- `[abc def] xyz` => should be false, because only [abc def] is selected
- `[abc def xyz]` => should be true, because the entire line has been selected
- the selection spans across multiple lines (true):

  ```
   abc [def xyz
   abc def xyz
   abc def] xyz
  ```

This will detect the last case:

```
var range = getTextAreaSelection(textarea),
    selection = textarea.value.substring(range[0], range[1]);

if(selection.indexOf('\n') !== -1)
  // do stuff...
```

But how do I handle the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check what the character before/after is:

```
textarea.value.charAt(range[0] - 1); // if it's `\r` or `\n` it's the first char of a line
textarea.value.charAt(range[1] + 1); // same fot last char of a line
```

If either or both return an empty string, it's the beginning/ending of the textarea value so that would also count as a full line.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way I can make the conditional check shorter? :) Right know the IF is huge :s

Comment: @Alex: You could do `~textarea.value.substring(range[0] - 1, range[0] + 1).indexOf("\n")` since `~` coerces `-1` into a falsy value and all other indices as a truthy value.